# Go back 1 step in navigationbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I want a button to have the same effect that pressing the back button in the navigation would have, where the view goes back to the last view.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 4):

Add a method to your view controller:

```
-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And add the button in IB, hook up the `touchupInside` event to the newly added `goBack:` method you just added.